# “Ich sah fünf Flugzeuge abheben.” – How to transform to the perfect tense?

Tags: word-order, perfect-tense, accusative-and-infinitive

I would like to say in German:

> I saw five planes taking off.

I think the answer is:

> Ich sah fünf Flugzeuge abheben.

Now I want to use the perfect tense.
My best guess is:

> Ich habe fünf Flugzeuge gesehen abheben.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the standard rules your *best guess* would be almost correct. It should be

> Ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben gesehen.

because *haben* and the perfect participle make up a frame for the complete object, hence *gesehen* comes last.

But...

... no rule without exception ;-)

In some cases, the perfect participle gets substituted by the infinitive when it follows another infinitive. This always happens with modal verbs, most of the time with *heißen*, *lassen* and *sehen*, and also with *fühlen*, *helfen* and *hören*. [See here at canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html?lang=en#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882) for sample phrases and as a reference.

So your sentence should really be:

> **Ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben sehen.**

Answer (score 12):

Transforming the following sentence:

> Ich sah fünf Flugzeuge abheben.

to perfect yields:

> **Ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben sehen.**

The rule is that if a perfect participle (Partizip II) follows an infinitive it takes the form of the infinitive too. So “gesehen“ becomes “sehen“.

“Ich habe fünf abhebende Flugzeuge gesehen“ is a correct sentence, but it is the perfect-tense equivalent of “Ich sah fünf abhebende Flugzeuge“. Thus it does not 100% correspond to “Ich sah fünf Flugzuge abheben.”

Answer (score -7):

> **Ich habe fünf abhebende Flugzeuge gesehen**;

Die von dir gesuchte Form, "**ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben gesehen**",

ist auch sprachlich, aber etwas unsauber, denke ich.

"*Ich habe es vermeiden können*" ist ein Beispiel der zweiten Form, das in der ersten Form nicht ausgedrückt werden kann. Daher ist die erste Form für das erste Beispiel vermutlich zu bevorzugen, um den Unterschied zu verdeutlichen.

Die erste Form enthält das **Partizip**. Der Unterschied ist der verschiedene Bezug der beiden Verben zu verschiedenen bzw. gleichen Agenten. Das Objekt dient als Trennzeichen, Hilfsverb und gebeugtes Verb dienen als Klammern.

Hier der Gedankengang zur zweiten Form:

- ich habe fünf Flugzeuge
- ich habe fünf Flugzeuge gesehen
- ich habe fünf Flugzeuge, die abheben
- ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben (ist vermutlich hochsprachlich falsch, ggf. aber Umgangssprache)
- ich habe fünf Flugzeuge, die abheben, gesehen
- **ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben gesehen** (also auch nur umgangssprachlich? Ich bin mir ehrlich gesagt nicht sicher)

Likewise, *"Ich sah Flugzeuge abheben"" and *"ich sah abhebende Flugzeuge"* may be used.

Comment: "Ich habe fünf Flugzeuge abheben sehen" ist die einzige Form, die du in deiner Liste nicht hast - Aber auch die einzige richtige - Heißt *Ersatzinfinitiv*, das Partizip Perfekt wird zum Infinitiv.